# Is there a natural way to define the inverse of a tensor?

Tags: matrices, inverse, tensors, inverse-function

I have a second rank tensor $\mu$, which is in my case a linear map from $S^3(\mathbb{R})$ to $S^3(\mathbb{R})$ where $S^3(\mathbb{R})$ are the $3 \times 3$ symetric matrices with real coefficients.

I was wondering if there exists a somehow "natural way" to define the "inverse tensor" of $\mu$. As an example, maybe I could state something like "$\mu$ is inversible if $\mu (E)$ is inversible for any $E \in S^3(\mathbb{R})$, and we pose $\mu^{-1}(E)=(\mu(E))^{-1}$"

Do you guys have some thoughts on this ? Any ideas are welcomed !

Possible answer :

As $\mu$ is a linear map from $E=S³(\mathbb{R})$ to $E$, it can be seen as a matrice $U$ of dimension $6 \times 6$ by fixing a base $\mathcal{B}$ of $E$. Then I could just say that $\mu$ is inversible if the matrice $U$ is, and set $\mu^{-1}$ the application from $E$ to $E$ such as it's matrice in the base $\mathcal{B}$ is $U^{-1}$. This definition seems very natural since it verifies

$$\mu \circ \mu^{-1} = Id_{E \rightarrow E}.$$

Comment: If $\mu$ maps matrices to matrices, shouldn't it be of rank $(2,2)$ ? But to answer your question, you should first think about what would qualify as an "identity tensor".

Comment: You're right it is a second rank tensor, my bad. I have updated the post thanks to your comment.

Comment: This unfortunately can't work in general: some tensorswon't have any inverse at all. For instance, consider a tensor of rank $5$ and look at it from the point of view of linear maps: the domain and codomain of the linear maps will have different dimension hence can't be invertible.

Comment: Yes indeed. I'm just lucky that in my configuration the tensor can be written as a square matrix.